# FreePascal: Casting object from Double -> Object -> Double works, but just Double doesn't

Tags: pointers, casting, integer, pascal

Another in the series of `TObject` to `Double` madness.

`SetPixel` requires a `Double` as its first argument (that is a pointer to a `IBlittable`).
`GetWindowByHWND` returns a `Double`.

This *does not* work (segfault):

```
var
  B: Double;
begin
  B := GetWindowByHWND(0);
  while (true) do SetPixel(B, 3, 3, $FFFFFF);
end.
```

Yet this *does*:

```
var
  B: IBlittable;
begin
  B := IBlittable(Floor(GetWindowByHWND(0)));
  while (true) do SetPixel(Double(Integer(B)), 3, 3, $FFFFFF);
end.
```

Here's the GetWindowByHWND method:

```
function GetWindowByHWND(Handle: Double): Double; STDCall;
var
  ReturnVal: IBlittable;
begin
  ReturnVal := TWindow.Create(Floor(Handle));
  GetWindowByHWND := Double(Integer(ReturnVal));
end;
```

Why does it work like this?

Does it have to do with some sort of "memory on the stack" weirdness that should never be used in real production code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the IBlittable reference keeps the interface from being deallocated, given the fact that you don't regard interface refcounting at all.

You can't simply start casting interfaces at random without refcounts messing up.

Comment: What is your recommended solution?

Comment: Use normal classes, or study the workings of interfaces better. And then specially their refcounting aspects.